# How to connect TCP/IP to k8s kind pods from host?

Tags: kubernetes, networking

As best I can infer from KIND's docs, host to guess networking sound like it is expected to just work, (except on windows/mac environments due to the nature of boot2docker like network topology on these networks. folks in this situation suggest using an openvpn gateway + port forwarding to gain network access).

Kindnet suggests even supporting ipv6 out of the box, though, I've not seen reported by `kubectl` or by iproute2 utill `ip` any ipv6 addresses other than loopback assigned in the stock configuration (`kind create cluster`). also enabling ipv6 as suggested by the KIND's docs seemed to break pod-to-internet connectivity (probably because my host is deployed in a ipv4 only environment, i only wanted ipv6 to get host to pod connectivity established.)

Anyway, on my experiment box described below, there was no ipv4 route to the pods or the exposed services, from the host created by `kind create cluster`

### Context

I am interested in a toy-k8s environment for locally testing kubectl deployment/spec files.

A prominent choice for a toy-k8s environment is Kind. This experiment was run on a debian-bookwork (debian 12) system using debian packaged docker and gccgo. Docker.io from apt, kind build with `go install` as per Kind's distribution docs. test user empowered with no password sudo and the docker group against debian's docker recommendation (for kind docker comparability).

A very simple `kind create cluster` worked very well for providing a viable kubennetes service.

But after launching some dockerhub nginx pods as a test, and exposing these as a service, I noticed that I could not route traffic host-to-pod over TCP/IP, despite the kind network having a network bridge to it, and there being a dedicated veth ptp link presumably to the kindnet CNI.

### Troubleshooting

I can see that pod's are being allocated ip addresses from the 10.244.0.0/24 pool and kindnet documents that it reserves the 10.244.0.0/16 network, networking pod-to-pod works fine and pod-to-internet works.

I partly suspect a debian_stable+kind_latest bug where the host fails to create a route for the k8s network. I tried manually assigning ip routes, eg `sudo ip route add 10.244.0.0/16 dev veth...` but this just timed out. I tried adding similar routes to the k8s bridge network but presumably this terminates to the k8s cluster members not the pods so it makes sense it doesn't route.

Am I forgetting something like assigning an ip address to my veth interface? i tried assigning 10.244.0.254, that didin't work, maybe a bad address?

are there other platforms where kind host-to-pod networking is known to work to compare generated configurations against?

Any context of what is expected from `kindnet` is appreciated.